# Is there any way to get driving directions to a location at a specified time of the day?

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to get driving directions in Google Maps to a location at a specified time of the day?

By that I mean the map should take into account the average traffic for that specific time frame and route accordingly. I am not looking for real time traffic. I want to be able to pre-plan my trip three days prior (in the evening) and want to know the best possible route on that day at that time.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**New Maps**

Head to [new Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/) and go to where you want to view traffic.

Clear the search box (yeah, the UX people were out that day).

Hover your mouse over the search area and underneath "Getting around" should appear with some options. Select "Traffic":

[image]

You can then select "Typical Traffic" and change the date/time of the traffic you are looking at:

[image]

Check out the map and try some different routes - avoid the red bits!

---

**Old Maps**

Head to old [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps?output=classic) and select your start and finish points as usual. Then select 'Traffic' from the dropdown at the top right:
[image: Traffic menu on Google Maps]

You should then get a menu on the lower left of the map that allows you to change the date/time of the traffic you are looking at:

[image]

Check out the map and try some different routes - avoid the red and black bits!